# Executing Javascript code "on the spot" in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a page in chrome which contains many textboxes and I wish to feed values automatically to them. I already have the list of name-value pairs, so if I could simple execute a series of Javascript commands on the form "document.getElementsByName(NAME)[0].value = VALUE;" I'll be done (I hope...)

So the question is - can I run a JS code "on the spot", or do I have to use a content script somehow?

Comment: What you mean "on the spot"? Something must "trigger" the code execution unless you want to use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Right click on the page and choose 'inspect element'. In the screen that opens now (the [developer tools](http://code.google.com/intl/us-US/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html)), clicking the second icon from the left @ the bottom of it opens a console, where you can type javascript. The console is linked to the current page.

Comment: How to make it run JQuery?

Comment: If JQuery is loaded in the page, you can use it in the console

Comment: After typing the code, do I have to click "run" anywhere?

Comment: @HighGPA Just user the [enter] key. To type multiple lines, use shift+enter

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how far it will get you, but you can execute JavaScript one line at a time from the [Developer Tool Console](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/console.html).

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I didn't think it was connected to the page; silly me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) if you want run bigger scripts in more convenient way and run them automatically by one click.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to execute the function inputted, yes, that is simple:

Use this JS code:

```
eval(document.getElementById( -- el ID -- ).value);
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried something like this? Put it in the head for it to work properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
         //using DOMContentLoaded is good as it relies on the DOM being ready for
         //manipulation, rather than the windows being fully loaded. Just like
         //how jQuery's $(document).ready() does it.

         //loop through your inputs and set their values here
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the Gadi was asking for.