# Can a user edit website's javascripts

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am building a website which uses a lot of javascripts. I want to know if a user can edit the js too along with seeing it.

For example, I have an ajax function which calls a.php. Can user just edit the js function in firebug or something similar to make it b.php which I want don't want to be available to everybody.

Similarly, I call an ajax function with parameter x. Is it possible for a user to make that parameter y and then call that function.

Comment: Let me be try to be clear here **Never Trust the client side, Authentication and validation must be on the server**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603836/executing-javascript-code-on-the-spot-in-chrome

Comment: Thank you. What should I do to ensure at server side that a php file is run from only a particular page and not from all pages..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that is front end, that means, `HTML`, `CSS` `javascript` in any of its forms or any other scripting client side languages can be modified and it is your job as a web developer to expect them to be modified by curiosity of the user or just to try and find vulnerabilities.

That is why while having client side validations (javascript in any form or just HTML5 ones), it is also of utter importance that you actually validate this stuff on server side, with whatever language you are using (`PHP`, `Ruby`, `ASP` just to give a few examples).

On Chrome, users can easily press `F12` on their keyboard to see your javascript/html/css code and try to modify it, we as web designers/developers do it as well for just inspiration, check out how something works, and well expect other people with different intentions to do it.

Same goes with Firefox, opera and pretty much any other web explorer.

Your job is not to prevent this, but to prevent that when someone changes something on the client side, the server side is ready to respond back in an appropriate way, preventing harm to the information on your servers.

To give a concrete example, that is why people take so much time in making sure queries to databases are sanitized, and not subjected to `sql injections`. More information about those here: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

So no, you can't prevent users from modifying your front end files, at most you can try some practices I've seen around like disabling right click (really annoying).

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to tell my php that it should run only if it is being called from a particular page.

Comment: That sir is called ajax. Do you know how ajax works? You can possibly parse the url and verify it is the one you want, if it is, load the function that calls the php script.

Answer (score 15):

Yes. Anything in the user's browser is under the control of the user.

You have control over nothing beyond the edge of your HTTP server.

Comment: Thank you. What should I do to ensure that atleast the php which is being called is right one.

Comment: I am sorry. Please let me explain. I have 2 pages, one for paid user, other for free user. Paid user can call b.php and free user can only call a.php. I want to ensure that free user doesn't just edit his page and call b.php. For that, what code do I need to put in b.php to make it realize whether the request is coming from 'paid' page or not.

Comment: How do you determine if a user is paid or free elsewhere on the site? Use that method.