# How to add a div element in mediaelement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, mediaelement.js

I want to add transparent div before **mejs-layers** class of **mediaelement.js** in WordPress. Using the below code doesn't add the test div inside mediaelement section

```
jQuery("<div>empty div</div>").insertBefore("div.mejs-layers");
```

However, when I try to add a div before my web-page components, it does

```
jQuery("<div>empty div</div>").insertBefore("h1");
```

Any idea how to add a div component to third party libraries?

Comment: Are you sure the div  exists by the time you execute `insertBefore`?

Comment: I am not sure. How can I test this?

Comment: Try to execute it in browser console and watch if it appears

Comment: Please, can you share some reference link?

Comment: @Himani https://stackoverflow.com/a/5603863/2482249

Comment: I don't know details concerning your plugin, but try to find its events in the docs. I think you need to execute your `insertBefore` on a kind of rendering event.

Comment: ok will check thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the mediaelement section is already in the DOM, when you're adding the div.

Comment: Please can you tell me how can I check if mediaelement elements are loaded?

Comment: I am able to add the div just before mediaelement section starts but not after that

Comment: That's what `insertBefore()` is supposed to do. If you want it after the opening tag, you should use `prepend()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your insertion code in the `success` callback when initiating the mediaelement.js call, it should work as you expect. Example:

```
$("video").mediaelementplayer({
    success: function (mediaElementObject, domObject) {
        $("<div>empty div</div>").insertBefore("div.mejs-layers");
    }
});
```